# Replace query ' sign

Tags: sql

I am having +chr(39)+ in my table that I want to replace it with '

example:  l+chr(39)+essai to be replace as l'essai

My query: `UPDATE dbo.Articles SET resume REPLACE(resume,'+chr(39)+',''')`

But error in at the ''', what' s wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need another quote at the end

```
UPDATE dbo.Articles SET resume = REPLACE(resume,'+chr(39)+','''')
```

It may be more focussed if you add a WHERE clause

```
WHERE resume like '%+chr(39)+%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server here.

' is used to escape special characters. You'll need a double '' (so your total becomes '''') to use the actual string '.

Comment: how about if you want to replace \ sign ?

Comment: You can just use '\', but again, that's if you're using SQL Server.